# tf.keras: feeding bool type variable along the input in model.fit method

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am building a model and I need to pass a bool type variable with True value with model.fit method and with False value with model.predict because I want need to run a condition(tf.condition or switch) function that works differently when the conditional bool variable is true or false. When I tried to feed it along the input, it gives me error with validation split as input shape is (89084,127) while bool is just a bool value. Can anyone suggest me how to pass this bool variable to the model?

My code is here:

**Model**

```
######### \no return sequences
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
global flag
flag=True
input_size=127
dummy=np.zeros((1,19),dtype=np.float64)
dummy=tf.convert_to_tensor(dummy)
embedding_size=100
lstm_size=128
learn_rate=0.01
drop_out=0.1
output_size=19

condition = Input( shape=[], dtype=bool,name = "condition")
#condition=K.placeholder(shape=(1,),dtype=tf.bool)
#----------------------------Model for current utterance--------------------------------
current_input=Input(shape=(input_size,)) 
emb_current = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size,weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=input_size, name='current_embed',trainable=False)(current_input)
out_current_b1=Bidirectional(LSTM(units=lstm_size, return_sequences=True))(emb_current )
attention_vector_current=attention(return_sequences=False)(out_current_b1)
out_current = Reshape((1,attention_vector_current.shape[1]))(attention_vector_current)
context1_input_da=Input(shape=(output_size,))
#-----------------------------Combined Model-------------------------------------------
def true_fn():
       
    prev_DA=Reshape((1,output_size))(context1_input_da)
    combined_train= Concatenate(axis=-1,name='true_train')([prev_DA, out_current])
    return combined_train
def false_fn():
  combined_without_previous = Concatenate(axis=-1,name='without_context')([out_current])
  hidden_without_previous =LSTM(units=lstm_size,name="lstm_test")(combined_without_previous)
  output_without_previous = Dense(units=19, activation='softmax')(hidden_without_previous)
  # Slice the output_without_previous 
  previous_scores = Concatenate(axis=-2, name='with_dummy_scores')([dummy, output_without_previous[:-1]])
  previous_scores= tf.expand_dims(previous_scores, 1)
  print('previous',previous_scores.shape)
  combined_test= Concatenate(axis=-1,name='False_test')([previous_scores, out_current])
  return combined_test

combined = K.switch(condition, true_fn, false_fn)  
hidden=LSTM(units=lstm_size)(combined)
output = Dense(units=len(unique_tag_set), activation='softmax')(hidden)

model = Model(inputs=[current_input,context1_input_da], outputs=output)
opt  = Adam(lr=learn_rate)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**Fit method:**

```
is_freeze= K.placeholder(shape=None,dtype=tf.bool)
is_freeze=True

history=model.fit([utt_minus_one,utt,prev_da_train], y_train,
                  epochs=1,batch_size=256,
                  shuffle = True, verbose = 1,
                  validation_split=0.2,
                  class_weight=custom_weight_dict)
```

How can I access this **is_freeze** bool variable in model or how can I pass it within fit method?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really the actual answer to your question but a more suitable way to solve the problem.

The problem about the method you asked is that you already make the model by the time you train but you need to make a new model with different structure as you change the way you make the layer entirely.

The trick is you don't need to make one model to do everything. You can use the same layers to build 2 or 3 models and they'll all share the same weights.

```
train_hidden=LSTM(units=lstm_size)(true_fn())
train_output = Dense(units=len(unique_tag_set), activation='softmax')(hidden)

inference_hidden=LSTM(units=lstm_size)(false_fn())
inference_output = Dense(units=len(unique_tag_set), activation='softmax')(hidden)

train_model = Model(inputs=[current_input,context1_input_da], outputs=train_output )
inference_model = Model(inputs=[current_input,context1_input_da], outputs=inference_output )
opt  = Adam(lr=learn_rate)
train_model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_model.fit(x,y)
inference_model.predict(x)
```

The problem is your `false_fn()` has these layers

```
  combined_without_previous = Concatenate(axis=-1,name='without_context')([out_current])
  hidden_without_previous =LSTM(units=lstm_size,name="lstm_test")(combined_without_previous)
  output_without_previous = Dense(units=19, activation='softmax')(hidden_without_previous)
```

Which will not get trained as you don't use this function when `fit` so there's no way you can use this model build with `false_fn()` to do anything unless you train it first.

Comment: I did not get your point for false_fn(). The input in train_model (context1_input_da) is actually gold standard label value in data set that is used as context while in inference_model the input ((context1_input_da) will be predicted value based on these three layers in false_fn() and used as context.  But both models will be using the input. But I'm unable to undertand your point  that these will not get trained. because we need these layers only with test data.

Comment: `because we need these layers only with test data` is why they will never not get trained as these layers will never be use when `fit`

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.

Comment: how inference model will share weights while its not compiled? I tried  it and results are very poor.

Comment: Compile only need when train. Of cource result is poor, you never train those layers!! I already said that though